# What makes a theorem "fundamental"?

Tags: soft-question

I've studied three so-called "fundamental" theorems so far (FT of Algebra, Arithmetic and Calculus) and I'm still unsure about what precisely makes them fundamental (or moreso than other theorems).

Wikipedia claims:

> The fundamental theorem of a field of mathematics is the theorem considered central to that field. The naming of such a theorem is not necessarily based on how often it is used or the difficulty of its proofs.

So I am left wondering: what *is* the main criterion for a theorem to be considered fundamental?

Why, for instance, is there no "Fundamental Theorem of Complex Analysis" (say, de Moivre's formula, for example), or "Fundamental Theorem of Euclidean Geometry" (e.g. Pythagoras' theorem)?

Does anyone have a source of a more-rigourous definition of "fundamental", in this context?

Comment: I suppose you could call Pythagoras' theorem the Fundamental Theorem of Euclidean Geometry

Comment: @vadim123 Yes! Well noted.

Comment: The fact that all others are build upon them.

Comment: @Lucian Then why are there no fundamental theorems of other branches of maths, like logic, statistics, number theory, etc.? Surely such theorems exist within these branches?

Comment: For logic there are [de Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). For number theory, see Arithmetic. In probability and statistics, there is the [law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: @vadim123,I think [Thales' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) is the fundamental one. From it follows similar triangles and from that Pythagoras.

Comment: In geometry, there is the Fundamental Theorem of Similarity.

Comment: @Lucian Regarding the Fundamental Theorem of Similarity, and following your first comment, how do all geometric theorems follow from this?

Comment: Pythagoras, for instance, is one of its immediate consequences.

Comment: I think the idea of a rigorous definition of "fundamental" is misguided. Category Theory gives us some rigorous ideas about what we mean by "natural", but most of us encounter the word in relation to natural numbers long before we hit category theory. "Fundamental" has all the foibles and ambiguities of a word in the english language, most of the time. The meaning derives from use rather than definition. It is, though, indicative of theorems which capture basic mathematical relationships and ideas.

Comment: There are branches of geometry in which similarity is irrelevant. Similar triangles on the surface of a sphere are congruent.

Comment: If Complex Analysis had a fundamental theorem, I would nominate the Cauchy Integral Formula. If the field had a second fundamental theorem, I would nominate the Riemann Mapping Theorem. Those two really are the *sine qua non* of the field.

Comment: To the op:  in case you're waiting for it, I think I've reached a form of my answer I can happily call "finished" unless I get compelling feedback otherwise.

Comment: OP asks "Does anyone have a source of a more-rigourous definition of "fundamental", in this context?". Gets a long list of examples of theorems which are called fundamental or not (without questioning their naming). Accepts this as the answer. What?!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't know what happened to my last edit, but there was a significant update where I added some info on Urysohn to the topology section and wrote out a punchline which addressed those questions directly. If I cannot figure out what happened, another revision will appear.

Comment: Another punchline is up, can someone confirm seeing it before I ctrl + c something else and lose all the work?

Comment: Also @MartinBrandenburg in case you were interested in the complete version, another punchline is complete. Thanks very much for your comment, I wouldn't have read my post again and seen it missing without that post.

Comment: There was a related question on Mathoverflow for a list of funadmental theorems in Mathematics: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25332/fundamental-theorems

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Let's examine some of these so-called "fundamental" theorems.

($1$) **[The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).**

> "Every natural number greater than $1$ has a unique representation as a product of primes."

This theorem about factorization establishes the [primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) as fundamental building blocks for studying numbers. This idea and the obsession with these numbers (who have an entire [theorem named after them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)) which are the core building blocks of all integers has sparked **multiple** entire fields of research. Almost all problems about integers in [Diophantine equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) makes use of this theorem, because it makes proving an **enormous** body of results vastly simpler and in many cases makes them possible where direct proof is impossible. Most fields in mathematics would probably be crippled without this theorem. And because of the **immense** advantage of unique factorization (which not all settings have) number theorists were led to develop the field of [algebraic number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory) where this theorem finds its ultimate generalization in the context of [Dedekind domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain). In fact, to underscore just **how good** unique factorization is:  if it were true that every [number ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_integers) had unique factorization, there are old proofs of [Fermat's last theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) which would have given us the result ages ago, instead of making us wait 350 years!

---

($2$) **[The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).**

> "Every polynomial of degree $n$ with coefficients in the complex numbers has exactly $n$ complex roots (counting multiplicity)."

Algebra has its roots in the study of polynomials (no pun intended). You learn about other topics in a high school course named "algebra," but good old polynomials were some of the first objects considered by mathematicians in this field. [Ring theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory) uses polynomials extensively, [group theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) was *created* to deal with the problem of understanding solutions to polynomials. [Field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29) would not be a thing without polynomials. And the fact that a polynomials is essentially *uniquely* determined by its roots (in the classical case of $\Bbb C$ certainly) is--like the FTA from ($1$)--essential in huge numbers of proofs in the subject, and without which, again, it probably would not be so much of an object of study, and certainly would be hundreds of years behind in results proven without it.

---

($3$) **[The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).**

> "If $f$ is a continuous, $\Bbb R$-valued function on an interval $[a,b]$ and for $a<x<b$ define
>
> $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
>
> Then $F(x)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$."

This theorem links the two biggest concepts in calculus:  derivatives, which measure rates of change, and integrals, which measure areas underneath curves--which have huge numbers of physical interpretations other than just the naive notion of "area." Before this theorem, computing integrals was a task of doing Riemann sums directly using hard limit arguments and a lot of work. This theorem revolutionized the field because it related integration to differentiation, a process which is **much** easier to perform because--for example--any function expressible in terms of elementary functions has an elementary function styled derivative. It destroyed excess computation time, and made the use of both tools much richer and formed the basis for the study of calculus in greater generality and in more applications. The FTC allows one to prove the [change of variables formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables) and [integration by-parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts). The former, which is basically the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) in its derivative form, is a basic tool in proving many [identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28mathematics%29), which are the basic things in any mathematician's toolbox. The latter--[Leibniz' product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) in derivative form--gives rise to the notion of a [weak derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative) and--for some very general notions about integration--allows one to rigorously explore ideas in areas such as [partial differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation), which are basically what describe most everything in the physical world. This idea founded several fields as well, including [differential geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry) and the idea of [differential forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) through [Stokes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem), which is something that has helped us understand huge areas in mathematical physics and high-dimensional analysis, and has advanced society itself an enormous amount.

---

($4$) **[The Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory).**

> Let $k$ be a field and $\overline{k}$ be its separable closure. Denote by $G_k=\text{Gal}\left(\overline{k}/k\right)$ the group of continuous field automorphisms of $\overline{k}$ which fix $k$ pointwise. Then there is an inclusion reversing bijection between subfields $k\subseteq K\subseteq\overline{k}$ and closed subgroups $H\le G_k$."

This is another theorem that launched a huge enterprise and--along with its applications--made Galois theory a topic which today finds applications in number theory, algebra, and beyond. The field itself is mostly settled now, but this, its main theorem has the staying power to make powerful advances in all the applications it has found, and has a central role in the [Langland's program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program), a current area of research which is massive and global in scale.

---

**Addendum (non "fundamental" fundamental theorems)**

Here I'll note that there are fundamental theorems in all areas, not just the ones which have theorems that possess the word "fundamental" in the title. This also means that this is just works of my opinion, and not necessarily what everyone else might consider the "most fundamental" theorem to the topic.

($1'$) **[Demorgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). (Fundamental Theorem of [Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic))**

> "If we have two logical statements, $P,Q$. Then the negation of $P\land Q$, is $\lnot P\lor\lnot Q$, and the negation of $P\lor Q$ is $\lnot P\land\lnot Q$."

This set of relations, which fundamentally links logic to set theory--replace statements with sets, $\land$ with $\cap$, $\lor$ with $\cup$ and $\lnot$ with set complement--allows for a greater exploration of how one can do mathematics in a way which utilizes mathematics itself. It is one of the first theorems in logic, and provides a basis also for the idea of quantifiers and the duality which states $\lnot (\forall x : P)\iff \exists x : \lnot P$, which is an idea used in mathematical proofs as a technique time and again. Never mind content, which the other theorems thus-far address:  without this, we'd have trouble proving *anything*!

---

($2'$) **[The law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). (Fundamental Theorem of [Analytical] Geometry)**

> "If three sides of a triangle have lengths $a,b,c$ and the angles opposite those sides are $A,B,C$ respectively, then the relation
>
> $$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(C)$$
>
> holds."

I choose this one, because the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), while excellent, is not the one that best generalizes. This notion of using this extra term, $2ab\cos(C)$ leads to the idea of an [inner-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), which is an idea exploited in functional analysis, and is a foundation for the study of [linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra), a subject without which **no** professional mathematician would function. It is essential in areas such as [functional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space), applied mathematics, mathematical physics, and much more. It's a revolutionary idea which allows us to change from [pure geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry) to the idea of [analytical geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry).

---

($3'$) **The [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) and [Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). (Fundamental Theorems of Statistics)**

> (CLT) "If we look at a bunch of averages of samples from our population of the same size, then their distribution looks like a [bell curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_curve)."
>
> (LLN) "If we take the average of some observations, then--so long as we make enough of them--we will get closer to what the real average of **all** the numbers is."

Here I do not think either can supersede the other. These two theorems together, form the basis for statistical analysis. Without the Central limit theorem, it would be difficult to impossible to analyze averages of [random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) in any sort of efficient way. It takes **very general** objects one could care about (usually interpreted as samples of data from a population) and allows us to make inferences with good confidence on our errors to better understand the world around us. Without it, civilization would not exist in this information age of the internet. Information is the basis for the kind of advanced understanding we have of objects and physical laws, and has allowed us to develop things like the internet, smart phones, cars, spaceships, and so much more. The LLN is what allows us to be confident in our use of data. That is:  without know much of *anything* about data we're dealing with (i.e. how it's distributed, which can **drastically** affect what we observe and what happens) we can **still** make **good** guesses about what will happen on average, which allows us safety to build on this information and achieve the same things as in the CLT.

---

($4'$) **[Tychonoff's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem) and [Urysohn's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma). (Fundamental Theorems of [Point Set] [Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology)**

> *(Tychonoff)* "A product of any collection of [compact spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space) is compact."
>
> *(Urysohn)* "A topological space is [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space) if and only if two closed sets can be separated by a continuous function."

These theorems are two of the most fundamental and often-applied theorems from classical topology. The applications of Tychonoff's theorem top all other topological theorems by a huge margin. While not necessarily central to topology itself, the field as a whole is built more horizontally than vertically, and Tychonoff's theorem is one of the results which realizes the immense utility and ubiquity of topological methods. With the advent of the modern definition of compact as finite subcovers of open covers replacing the old notion from [metric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space), this result stands at a turning-point in the history of topology. Along with the modern definition of [continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function), compact spaces are the new ABCs of modern mathematics as finite sets were in the classical days. Almost nowhere in modern mathematics will one see a proof about an object where topological concepts do not occur, and compact sets being the "nicest" sorts of sets, knowing that your favorite object is compact (or [locally compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) et cetera) is an advantage in proving results that **cannot** be understated. Furthermore, the idea behind using a [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) instead of the [box topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) originated in Tychonoff's work, and from a [very general standpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), this idea is somehow the most "right" way to think about topological products, so that--aside from the theorem itself--the ideas of its proof are also fundamental.

Urysohn's lemma, while less applied overall, is more central within the field of topology itself. Topology came as a refinement to the old notion of a metric space, but naturally metric spaces already had a great deal of theorems proven about them, so it was a worthwhile enterprise to find topological descriptions of a space which implies ones favorite space is a metric space and hence allowed for the use of all the hard work everyone had put into metric spaces to be applied to one's favorite spaces in this new context. This is the basic idea behind [metrization theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem). Urysohn's lemma is a foundational result which helps one to prove many of these theorems and hence is very useful withing the field itself. While not carrying as much utility overall as Tychonoff, it is used to prove more theorems **in** topology than is Tychonoff, which is more useful for proving theorems **with** topology.

---

($5'$) **[The Three Isomorphism Theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem). (Fundamental Theorems of Group and Ring Theory)**

> Again there is a lot since there are three theorems and each is slightly different for groups vs rings, so I'll leave the link for those interested in reading about them.

These three results constitute the bedrock of group and ring theories--areas in modern algebra which study symmetry and algebraic relations in their most general forms. Group and rings are both primarily understood by examining sub and quotient groups/rings. The idea of a [homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) is quite possibly the backbone of **all** modern mathematics. It's a notion of a function which *preserves structure*, in other words it's a notion of how similar two objects are while taking into account only the relevant properties we care about. In the case of groups, we care if we preserve the main bit of structure in a group, the group multiplication. In the case of rings, they need to preserve multiplication **and** addition, the two ring operations. The same holds for fields, [boolean algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), this list can go on ad nauseum, so I'll stop here before I write an entire paragraph for the list of things we use homomorphisms for. The isomorphism theorems are essential building blocks towards understanding the fundamental essence of homomorphisms and how to think about the objects that naturally arise in their study, namely [subobjects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject) (i.e. subgroups or rings) and quotient objects (i.e. quotient groups and rings). Thanks to the idea of a [composition series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series) and the celebrated [Jordan-Hölder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series#Uniqueness:_Jordan.E2.80.93H.C3.B6lder_theorem), it tells us that a thorough understanding of homomorphisms can give us essentially unlimited insight into the structure of groups.

---

($6'$) **[Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). (Fundamental Theorem of [Complex Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis))**

> "Let $f(z)$ be [holomorphic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) on the open set $U\subseteq\Bbb C$. Let $z\in U$ and $\gamma=\gamma_z: [0,1]\to U$ be a [simple, closed curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordanCurve.html) around $z$, [oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_%28geometry%29) positively. Then
>
> $$f(z)=\oint_{\gamma}{f(\xi)\over \xi-z}\,\mathrm{d}\xi.$$

Cauchy's integral formula deserves to be called "fundamental" in complex analysis if anything does. It proves the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) which is **hugely** important in complex analysis, [algebraic geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry), and [analytic number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_number_theory)--where it connects to the idea of a [$\zeta$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and distributions of primes in a very general setting. It proves the [argument principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) which led to the idea of [branch cuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point) and multi-valued functions. This allowed us to more concretely understand the [complex logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) and root functions in sufficient generality in such a genius way that it basically **jump started the field of topology** through the notion of a [Riemann surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface). Finally, this result establishes that a single complex derivative ensures infinite differentiability and a local power series everywhere on an open set where a function is holomorphic, completely abolishing the notion that complex-differentiable and real-differentiable functions are behave similarly. This is what makes classical complex analysis such an immensely beautiful subject, the rigidity of the functions gives them amazing properties real functions cannot compete with for the very mild condition of being differentiable.

---

($7'$) **[The Artin Reciprocity Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_reciprocity_law). (Fundamental Theorem of [Class Field Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory))**

> "Let $K/k$ be an [abelian extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_extension) of fields and $\mathfrak{c}$ be an admissible cycle for this extension. Then the [Artin map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArtinMap.html)
>
> $$I(\mathfrak{c})\to \text{Gal}(K/k)$$
>
> is surjective with kernel $P_{\mathfrak{c}}\mathfrak{N}(\mathfrak{c}$) (described in the articles cited, omitted for brevity)."

Artin's reciprocity law is the ultimate generalization of [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) a theorem first proved by [Gauß](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) and lauded by him as the "golden theorem." Combined with the [Hasse principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle), it describes an incredible fact about [quadratic forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) and quadratic fields. These forms are heavily studied objects. Even today interesting theorems from many areas--such as the [dynamical systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) approach of [Margulis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigory_Margulis) to problems in fields such as [Diophantine approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation), and [$\vartheta$-functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) and hence [modular forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form)--are proven about them. Alongside the work of [Hecke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Hecke) and [Tate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%27s_thesis) these forms are of huge importance. In the general case, it establishes norms as very special objects, and connects the [idèle class group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelic_algebraic_group#Ideles) to the Galois group of a field extension in a beautiful and deep way. This is the foundation of modern ideas related to the [Hilbert symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol), the [Kronecker-Weber theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem), and the Langland's program (before mentioned).

---

($8'$) **[Parseval's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) and the [Plancherel Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem). (Fundamental Theorems of [Fourier Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis))**

> *(Parseval)* "Let $f,g$ be functions of period $2\pi$ with [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)
>
> $$f(x)\sim \sum_{n\in\Bbb Z} a_ne^{inx},\quad g(x)\sim\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}b_ne^{inx}$$
>
> Then the inner-product of the $\ell^2(\Bbb Z)$ functions, $(a_n),(b_n)$ is equal to
>
> $${1\over\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x."$$
>
> *(Plancherel)* "Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the Fourier transform on $(L^1\cap L^2)(\Bbb R)$ with normalization
>
> $$\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)=\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
>
> Then the continuous extension of $\mathcal{F}$ to $L^2(\Bbb R)$ is an [isometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) (in fact a [unitary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator))."

The study of Fourier analysis goes back [hundreds of years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis#History) (and prototypes date back much farther). The Parseval formula transforms questions about [periodic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function)--which are a class of what are arguably one of the most important in all of mathematics--into those about its Fourier series, where techniques involved with [sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence). Together with its generalizations, this greatly simplifies the study of functions to understanding their Fourier series (more on this after Plancherel). The Plancherel theorem establishes a truly *remarkable* duality between functions and their Fourier transforms. Because of the [myriad properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform) of this transform, one can transfer very hard problems into much easier ones. In [differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation), one can turn differentiation (a very hard process to deal with in general) to questions about polynomials:  objects studied since antiquity. In applied mathematics, one uses Fourier analysis and things like the [sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) to reconstruct [signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing) from sampled data. This is what powers digital music, your ability to hear people over wireless phones, and a nearly infinite list of other things. Indeed, to do justice to the sheer magnitude and variety of uses of Fourier analysis and this duality established by Plancherel, would take three answers as long as this one to do a true modicum of justice. It is used in topology, [representation theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory), all forms of number theory (in things like the [Poisson summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)), and on and on and on. Parseval embodies analysis on the [circle group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group)--the prototype for general periodic functions--an idea which has proven to have a lot of mileage.

The two of them together underpin the works of Fourier analysis, a subject which has generalized to [locally compact groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_group) and their [characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_group) by the miracle of the [Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure). This allows this fruitful and powerful field reign in **very** general problems, and is the source of entire industries of and careers in mathematics.

---

**The Punchline** There are a lot of things which make a theorem "fundamental" to a field.

The $4$ with "official" status have a variety of reasons for their names. ($1$) is extremely old (due to Euclid). It is also powerful and useful in proving things in arithmetic (i.e. number theory). ($2$) gets the name as a product of history. To see how much, one considers that [Cardano's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) for solving cubics was first used to win some of the old math contests from the 1500s. Algebra has branched off a lot since, but for a long time it was much simpler in scope, and unique factorization of polynomials found itself as a long-standing central interest and has kept its name due to this history. ($3$), like ($1$), richly deserves its name:  the huge conceptual leap to connect the two different ideas of differentiation and integration is perhaps the single result which it is most satisfying to call "fundamental." Finally ($4$) stands at the top of its theory. It qualitatively embodies the philosophy of Galois theory in the capstone of the subject. No other result is as reflects the culmination of a field better than the FTGT. Notice, that it is not used a great deal to prove more results within Galois theory itself, here the result simply stands at the end of a long road, rather than near the beginning.

There are myriad reasons to lack a "fundamental theorem." In ($1'$), it would be strange to have a single, fundamental result. If the entire field of logic depended on one result, all of mathematics would be as well, which would either make this result unreasonably powerful or mathematics as a whole ridiculously simple.

For ($2'$), the field--as in ($4'$)--the results build more horizontally, so because of the diversity it makes less sense to name something "fundamental."

In ($3'$) and ($5'$), one notes that: (i) they have multiple results which are fundamental, no single one takes center stage and (ii) **the chosen names are just better**. Calling something "the fundamental theorem of [blah]" underscores--and can slightly over-inflate--a result's importance, but it makes it a lot less descriptive. The LLN and CLT are best with the name they have, as are the isomorphism theorems.

Finally ($6'$), ($7'$), and ($8'$) share the distinction that their theorems are named after the geniuses who proved them. This is more and more common in modern days, especially. Lang calls Artin Reciprocity the Fundamental Theorem of Class Field Theory, and most would probably agree. However, its official name is still "Artin reciprocity."

On the whole:  what makes the theorems we have "fundamental," **in name** is often a combination of the amount of history the subject and result have. For ($1$) and ($2$) especially, the fields are extremely old, whereas subjects like analysis, group/ring theory, and topology don't date back nearly as far. What makes all these results more "fundamental" **in spirit** is their incredible power and flexibility. These are some of the results which have helped shape the fields they correspond to. Some motivate a great deal of further research, some provide the key ingredients for an absurd number of proofs, some act as ambassadors between subjects in a way that links them much more strongly than others.

This multiplicity of reasons means that it's **fundamentally a flawed idea** to attach particular importance just to the official name "fundamental," or hope for a very insightful and "right" definition of what that means. If you look at the two lists, the "unofficial" list ended up being twice as long as the official one, and some of the unofficial ones--such as ($6'$)-($8'$)--are perhaps more "fundamental" to their subjects than ($2$). So any definition tailored to fit the current state-of-affairs which also did justice to the name "fundamental" would probably need to include a few of the results in the unofficial list and could not be a good definition since it is clear that it is not always used.

Comment: Very interesting answer @Adams Hughes. What about fundamental lemma of calculus of variations?

Comment: I think it would be better to remove the section of the supposed FT of Linear Algebra, because (1) few people (essentially a following of G. Strang who pushed the term) use that term, (2) it is not a theorem of linear algbera (which should be about linear maps) at all, but about matrices over the real numbers; it depends on an inner product and has no clear counterpart over general fields; (3) therefore the "unique decomposition" and (far fetched) link to reductive groups has no ground.

Comment: Agreed with @MarcvanLeeuwen: Without looking at the link, I thought that it would be the dimension theorem.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen and Quang Hoang (no double tags :/ ): Thank you, gentlemen. I included that one because of the name on the article and assumed I was crazy for not having heard of it that way when I learned the subject, but I quite agree:  it didn't feel right including it. It doesn't feel like any sort of thing one would call **the** central result of a field, and the answer is better without it.

Comment: Calling Tychonoff's theorem fundamental to topology is very, very weird...

Comment: Sentences like "Algebra is fundamentally the study of polynomials." ruin this answer. Also, some theorems are just some useful yet common theorem in the field. How is Tikhonov's theorem the fundamental theorem of point set topology? Or the cosine rule (!!!) a fundamental theorem of analytic geometry. I think the answer is just putting words in the mouth of some fields, and simply drifting off...

Comment: (It is known the term "Fundamental theorem of Algebra" is a product of historical inertia rather than a general agreement in the community of algebraists!)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I agree with your statement about algebra, that I've fixed. I chose others in the "unofficial list," such as Tychonoff based primarily upon how applicable and flexible I've found the result to be in general. Unlike many of the fields, topology doesn't seem to have a very strong theorem, that one proves as one of the first "big results," that seems to underpin a lot of the ideas in the subject, this partly due to the flexibility of the subject, IMO. As such for that one I chose the result that underscores that flexibility and applicability to other areas.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Similarly, I made the decision with the law of cosines because it has some very historically significant ideas in its development, and again I cannot say that the law of cosines is fundamental in the sense that it underpins a great deal of results in geometry, but it marks an interesting point in the history and the seeds of important modern ideas, so in a sense it is a theorem fundamental to the development and use of the mathematics of classical geometry in modern areas, but I agree with your statement that it doesn't fit things face-value like the "real" fundamental theorems.

Comment: I feel like Urysohn's Lemma is definitely the more fundamental one. It is used to prove the big metrization theorems, which seem to me to be the real holy grails for point-set.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez in my first response to Pedro, I explain my choice of Tychonoff. If that explanation still does not resonate with you based on circumstances, I'm absolutely open to an argument in favor of others.

Comment: @AdamHughes It seems to me some fields have these fundamental theorem as a result of them being a bit more old than others. For example, calculus or Galois theory were developed from the ground up and in a rather messy way, and it took the work of many good mathematicians to get them into a perfect shape. Thus, these fundamental results were somehow the pinnacle of years of polishing. General topology on the other hand strikes me more as an ad hoc creation to provide a more general view of known fields, and as such spreads and reaches no pinnacles.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff perhaps if I changed the wording a bit to "Theorem from topology fundamental to mathematics" or something? I don't want to delete the whole thing, because I think the actual content is interesting, but I do see your point on how the field is a bit ad hoc (this is also how I feel about linear algebra, and why I opted to delete that "Fundamental theorem" entirely in an earlier incarnation.

Comment: @JHance I actually reviewed the shorting of Urysohn and I think I agree with you in that it's more relevant within the field of topology itself. I'm leaving for errands soon, but I will definitely put them both up in that section when I get back and work on the next revision, at least modulo whatever suggestions Pedro or Mariano have that might make me rethink the content of that section.

Comment: @JHance I'd love to hear feedback you have on the revised topology section, if any.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think I'm mostly happy with this as a (tentative) final version now that I've added a clarifying punchline and modified some of the sections you gave that excellent feedback on. If you have the time, please take a look and give an appraisal, your previous advice was very helpful in shaping the linguistic revisions and the tone of the punchline.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I've updated the topology section with what I think is a better way of phrasing my reasoning for the choice made (and also, added Urysohn for more internal-to-topology fundamentalness). If you have any other feedback, I very much welcome it.

Comment: This answer was last edited 5 years ago and I am probably way out of my depth anyway, but doesn't the fundamental theorem of linear algebra, i.e. dimV=dim(kerT)+dim(imT), belong to this list as well? It's basically the starting point of linear algebra, relates the fundamental subspaces that come attached to every linear map, which are the objects this field studies and is used to prove plenty of other important results. Given linear algebra's general importance, doesn't it deserve a spot on this list?

Comment: @V.Ch. That theorem actually *was* in an earlier iteration of this answer. See the second comment for why it was (I think correctly) removed.

Comment: @AdamHughes, but what I'm talking about is phrased entirely in terms of linear maps over finite-dimensional vector spaces, arguably the main subject of study in linear algebra, does not involve any concepts outside bases (which is as basic as it gets in this subject) and serves as foundation for plenty of important results. From what I understand in the earlier iteration you posted Strang's version (iirc he phrases it in terms of the null and column space of a matrix and its transpose) and not what I'm talking about (this is essentially Sheldon Axler's version from Linear Algebra Done Right).

Comment: @AdamHughes I agree with the 2nd coment and its assessment of Strang's fundamental theorem (frankly, I don't like it myself, but who am I to talk compared to Strang), but the theorem in Axler's formulation is short, elegant, requires no external concepts like inner products and is a stepping stone to important results in the subject. In my humble opinion it deserves a mention. Also thanks for the speedy reply, I did not expect it at all.

Comment: **"...I cannot say that the law of cosines is fundamental in the sense that it underpins a great deal of results in geometry..."**. @AdamHughes: [The half-angle formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456365/the-theoretical-importance-of-the-half-angle-formulas) underpin a lot of results in geometry. And, probably, not only in geometry (see, for example, [Demaerel's proof of the FTA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456365/the-theoretical-importance-of-the-half-angle-formulas/4472376#4472376)).

Answer (score 17):

Just a little addendum after @Adam Hughes' nice answer.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space. The information $I(A)$ of an event $A$ (any element of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$) is given by $I(A)=f(P(A))$, denoting by $f$ a real function on $[0,1]$.

Then one has the

> **Fundamental theorem of information** (FTI)
>
> The Shannon entropy $f(x):=x\ln \frac{1}{x}+(1-x)\ln\frac{1}{1-x}$
> is the unique continuous solution of the fundamental equation of information (FEI)
> $$f(x)+(1-x)f\left(\frac{y}{1-x}\right)=f(y)+(1-y)f\left(\frac{x}{1-y}\right) ~~(*)$$
> on  $D:=\{(x,y)~|~ x\in [0,1), y\in[0,1), x+y\leq 1\}$.

The Shannon entropy plays a fundamental role in information theory, information geometry (it even generates Kullback Leibler divergences), and in many applications. There exists even an analogue of the FEI in number theory; for the whole exposition I refer to
*Kontsevich, The $1\frac{1}{2}$-logarithm.* Composition Math. 130 (2002).

Apart from applications *et* *similia*, I believe that it is the formulation of the FTI *via* functional equations that makes it interesting: after all, many important functions in mathematics are defined as solutions of functional equations (*in primis* the exponential function): the Shannon entropy becomes one of them.

Comment: Where does equation (*) come from? Why is it so important? (sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: the equation is important because comes from the axioms that the quantity called "information" should reasonably satisfy. One reference could be http://books.google.ch/books?id=9Xsj7AWmV8UC&printsec=frontcover&dq=On+measures+of+information+and+their+characterizations&hl=it&sa=X&ei=zW0oVN-bNeeS7AbH6IC4Dw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=On%20measures%20of%20information%20and%20their%20characterizations&f=false