# Why is it called the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, soft-question

The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is easy enough to understand, saying that every integer greater than 1 is either prime or is the product of a unique combination of prime numbers.

What I don't understand is why this is "fundamental." This may have massively important implications in number theory and cryptography and whatever else, but in terms of *arithmetic*, which I think of as adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing, it doesn't really actually seem to have that much importance....I don't see why it should be so *fundamental*.

Can someone explain its importance, or why it isn't called perhaps the "Fundamental Theorem of Number Theory"?

I would expect the Fundamental Theorem of *Arithmetic* to be something.

Comment: [Relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem).

Comment: Number Theory is the "modern" name of Arithmetic.

Comment: Also relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947442/what-makes-a-theorem-fundamental/

Comment: The word arithmetic comes from the Greek word arithmos, meaning number. There is an entire book in the Bible called Numbers. When Jews translated the Torah into Greek around the third century BC (see [Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint)), the name of that book was Arithmoi.

Comment: @Lucian: To add on the conspiracy here, the Hebrew word for "theory" in the mathematical context (e.g. set theory) is the same word as the Torah. So the old testament had an entire book about number theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I know ! :-) There's an entire scene in Darren Aronofsky's 1998 movie *Pi* about it. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because *Arithmetic* is another name for *Number Theory*.

Unique factorization was used widely for ages without anyone bothering to prove it or even feeling any need for a proof. It was Gauss that recognized this and finally proved it in *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* in 1801.

The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is also important because it does *not* hold in all number rings (that is, rings of integers of an algebraic number field). Attempts to understand this led to the important development of ideal numbers by Kummer and Dedekind and the birth of algebraic number theory and modern algebra.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/83987/589.

Comment: Your final paragraph totally lost me. Not sufficiently versed in terminology. But thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @Aerovistae Consider for example numbers of the form $a + b \sqrt{-5}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Some of these numbers have more than one factorization. But the ideals in this domain can be factored uniquely as products of prime ideals.

Comment: @Aerovistae, for further and simpler examples of failure of unique factorization see the first half of [these slides](http://www.shsu.edu/stc008/SAMtalk120308.pdf).